# manage button visibility present fragment by Mainactivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi I have a problem regarding the creation of a method that manages the visibility of a button present in a fragment and manage it from Mainactivity, I tried with the simple .setVisibility and it returned the error of null object, therefore it did not hide the button in a condition dictated by me below I show you the code:

MainActivity:

```
private StorageReference mStorageRef;
public Random mRandom;
public TextView mCounterCrd;
public ImageView mImgCrediti;
int StringCrd;
public RewardedAd rewardedAd;
private com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
public InterstitialAd mAdMobInterstitialAd;
public final int NR_SOUND = 1;
public int mSoundCoin;
public SoundPool mSound;
public ConsentForm form;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Inizializzazione Archiviazione Cloud
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    //Image Crediti Init
    mImgCrediti = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgCrediti);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    //Costruttore dei suoni SoundPool
    AudioAttributes audioattributi = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build();
    mSound = new SoundPool.Builder().setAudioAttributes(audioattributi).setMaxStreams(NR_SOUND).build();
    mSoundCoin = mSound.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.smb_coin, 1);

    //contatore crediti
    mCounterCrd = findViewById(R.id.counter_crd);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Lettura Crediti", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Credit = sharedPreferences.getString("Crediti", String.valueOf(StringCrd));
    StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(Credit);
    mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));

    if(StringCrd < 2){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if(StringCrd > 1){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    if(StringCrd >= 1){
        //Sfondo Random all'apertura
        mRandom = new Random();
        int i = mRandom.nextInt(3);
        if(i==0){
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tx =  fm.beginTransaction();
            fragment_1 fragmentview = new fragment_1();
            tx.replace(R.id.frame_place, fragmentview);
            tx.commit();
        }
        if(i==1){
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tx =  fm.beginTransaction();
            fragment_2 fragmentview = new fragment_2();
            tx.replace(R.id.frame_place, fragmentview);
            tx.commit();
        }
        if(i==2){
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tx =  fm.beginTransaction();
            fragment_3 fragmentview = new fragment_3();
            tx.replace(R.id.frame_place, fragmentview);
            tx.commit();
        }
    }

    if(StringCrd >= 1){
        String clickZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(clickZero);
        StringCrd--;
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
    }

    //Funzione se i crediti < 1
    if(StringCrd == 0 ){
        String clickZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(clickZero);
        StringCrd = 0;
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tx =  fm.beginTransaction();
        fragment_2 fragmentview = new fragment_2();
        tx.replace(R.id.frame_place, fragmentview);
        tx.commit();
    }

    loadVideo();
    ceckForCosent();
}

@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
public void ClickUP(View view) {
    //Vibration control
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    assert vib != null;
    vib.vibrate(30);

    //Funzione della Guida
    if(StringCrd < 2){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(StringCrd > 1){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    if(StringCrd > 1){

        //Funzione Decrementa Crediti
        String Credit = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(Credit);
        StringCrd--;
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));

        //Scelta Sfondo click su avanti
        mRandom = new Random();
        int i = mRandom.nextInt(3);
        if(i==0){
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tx =  fm.beginTransaction();
            fragment_1 fragmentview = new fragment_1();
            tx.replace(R.id.frame_place, fragmentview);
            tx.commit();
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        if(i==1){
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tx =  fm.beginTransaction();
            fragment_2 fragmentview = new fragment_2();
            tx.replace(R.id.frame_place, fragmentview);
            tx.commit();
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        if(i==2){
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tx =  fm.beginTransaction();
            fragment_3 fragmentview = new fragment_3();
            tx.replace(R.id.frame_place, fragmentview);
            tx.commit();
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }

    //Funzione se i crediti < 1
    if(StringCrd == 1 ){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        StringCrd = 1;
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
    }

    if(StringCrd == 0 ){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        StringCrd = 0;
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
    }
}

public void loadInterstitialConsent(){

}

public void loadInterstitialNonConsent(){

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Funzione Visible della Guida
    if(StringCrd < 2){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(StringCrd > 1){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //Funzione Visible della Guida
    if(StringCrd < 2){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(StringCrd > 1){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(R.string.Uscita_App)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.Risposta_Uscita_Si, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.Risposta_Uscita_No, null)
            .show();
}

@Override
public void decrementa() {
    //Vibration control
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    assert vib != null;
    vib.vibrate(30);

    //Funzione Decrementa Crediti sul button download
    if(StringCrd >= 1){
        String Credit = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd = Integer.parseInt(Credit);
        StringCrd--;
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
    }
    //Funzione se i crediti < 0
    if(StringCrd < 1 ){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd = Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        StringCrd = 0;
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
    }

    if (mAdMobInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mAdMobInterstitialAd.show();
    }else{
        interstitialAd.show();
    }

    //Funzione Visible della Guida
    if(StringCrd < 2){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(StringCrd > 1){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

public void ClickVideo(View view) {
    //Vibration control
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    assert vib != null;
    vib.vibrate(30);

    //Video a Premio
    if(this.rewardedAd.isLoaded()) {
        RewardedAdCallback callback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                //Aggiunta di crediti
                String Credit = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
                StringCrd = Integer.parseInt(Credit);
                int coins = 2;
                StringCrd += coins;
                mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
                //Toast nome Crediti
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "2 Rapp Coins" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0,200);
                toast.show();
                //Play Sound
                mSound.play(mSoundCoin,0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                super.onRewardedAdOpened();
                loadVideo();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                super.onRewardedAdClosed();
                RewardedAdClosed();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(int i) {
                super.onRewardedAdFailedToShow(i);
            }
        };
        this.rewardedAd.show(this, callback);

    } else {
    }

    //Funzione Visible della Guida
    if(StringCrd < 2){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(StringCrd > 1){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

private void ceckForCosent(){
    ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    String[] publisherIds = {"pub-9034900799287221"};
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
            switch (consentStatus){
                case PERSONALIZED:
                    showPersonalizedAds();
                    break;
                case NON_PERSONALIZED:
                    showNonPersonalizedAds();
                    break;
                case UNKNOWN:
                    if(ConsentInformation.getInstance(getBaseContext()).isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown()){
                        requestConsent();
                    }else{
                        showPersonalizedAds();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String reason) {
        }
    });
}

private void requestConsent() {
    URL privacyUrl = null;
    try {
        // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy URL.
        privacyUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/partner-sites/");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle error.
    }
     form = new ConsentForm.Builder(MainActivity.this, privacyUrl)
            .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                    // Consent form loaded successfully.
                    showForm();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                    // Consent form was displayed.
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormClosed(
                        ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                    // Consent form was closed.
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                    // Consent form error.
                }
            })
            .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withAdFreeOption()
            .build();
     form.load();
}

public void showPersonalizedAds() {
    loadInterstitialConsent();
}

public void showNonPersonalizedAds() {
    loadInterstitialNonConsent();
}

public Bundle getNonPersonalizedAdsBundle(){
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("npa","1");
    return extras;
}

public void showForm() {
    if(form == null){
    }
    if(form != null){
        form.show();
    }else{
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
        interstitialAd.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
    //Salvataggio Crediti nel metodo On Destroy
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Lettura Crediti", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Credit = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Crediti", Credit).apply();

    //Funzione Visible della Guida
    if(StringCrd < 2){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(StringCrd > 1){
        String CreditZero = mCounterCrd.getText().toString();
        StringCrd =Integer.parseInt(CreditZero);
        mCounterCrd.setText(String.valueOf(StringCrd));
        mImgCrediti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

Fragment Activity fragment_1:

```
ImageView bntDwn_1;
FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
StorageReference storageReference;
StorageReference ref;
Comunication com_1;
private int count = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    bntDwn_1 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dwn_1);
    com_1 = (Comunication)getActivity();
    bntDwn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;
            if(count == 1){
                download();
                com_1.decrementa();
            }else{
                String toastMessage = fragment_1.this.getResources().getString(R.string.Sfondo_Salvato_in_Download);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0,200);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void download(){
    storageReference= firebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    ref = storageReference.child("fourapper_forpaper_1 (1).jpeg");
    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String url = uri.toString();
            downloadFiles(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "ForPaper_1", ".jpeg", url);
            //Toast Traducibile
            String toastMessage = fragment_1.this.getResources().getString(R.string.Sfondo_Salvato_in_Download);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0,200);
            toast.show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            //Toast Traducibile
            String toastMessage = fragment_1.this.getResources().getString(R.string.Download_Fallito);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0,200);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}

private void downloadFiles(Context context, String destinationDirectory, String fileName, String fileExtension, String Url){
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName +fileExtension);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

}

Fragment Layout fragment_1:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sfondo_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sfondo_1"
    android:src="@drawable/forpaper_1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dwn_1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/scarica"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_download"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

What I want to do is hide the imageview button dwn_1 from MainActivity, I tried with the simple method of implementing a button by calling the methods:

```
mbtnCrd = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dwn_1);
mbtnCrd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

inside an if () function, but it didn't work because it told me that I was invoking a virtual method or that the object was Null

for this I ask you if there is a method to manage the visibility of the buttons present in fragment by MainActivity, I hope you can help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the Btn located in your fragment from the activity you can Set up broadcasts.

In Activity when you want to hide the Btn:

```
    Intent hideBtn = new Intent("hide_event");
    sendBroadcast(hideBtn);
```

In your Fragment listen to this broadcast.

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             myBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        }
    };
    getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("hide_event"));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are trying to access dwn_1 from your activity? but that view belongs to your fragment. That is why  you get a null object when you call:

> findViewById(R.id.dwn_1);

You could do something like this

```
class MainActivity {
    YourFragment fragment:

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //SomeCode
        fragment = new YourFragment()
        //SomeCode
    } 

    private void hideView(){
        fragment.hideImage()
    }
}
```

In your fragment

```
class YourFragment {
    private ImageView mbtnCrd;

    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Some code
        bntDwn_1 = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dwn_1);
    }

    public void hideImage(){
        bntDwn_1.setVisibility(View.GONE):
    }
}
```

Then call hideView() method whenever you want to hide that view.

Comment: in fact I would like to know what method to adopt to invoke the button dwn_1 of the fragment in MainActivity, thanks